# Intellij Save workspace settings for multiple instances

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

I need to work on two different projects have different setup for maven, formatting, etc. Right now i can start two instances of intellij and also put different settings in them, but this lasts only until i close the instance.

When i restart my idea and open open the projects in different windows, again the same set of workspace settings appear for both of them.

Anybody has solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA Maven settings are project specific. Once you configure Maven for a project, it will be used only for this project and another project can have a completely different Maven version. The same is for JDK and almost any other setting that may need to differ.

Code style settings also allow you to store the formatting with the project instead of using the global IDE code style common for all the projects.